# How to wrap every 2 elements inside a container in a div, except the ones with a certain class out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grouping

I want to group every 2 images in a different div but leaving the wider ones with only one image. That's the HTML:

```
<figure id="container">
    <img src="001.jpg" class="single" />
    <img src="002.jpg" class="single" />
    <img src="003.jpg" />
    <img src="004.jpg" />
    <img src="005.jpg" />
    <img src="006.jpg" />
    <img src="007.jpg" />
    <img src="008.jpg" class="single" />
    <img src="009.jpg" />
    <img src="010.jpg" class="single" />
</figure>
```

So, I don't know what jQuery scripts to use to group these respecting the class "single", the wider ones. I want:

```
<figure id="container">
  <div><img src="001.jpg" class="single" /></div>
  <div><img src="002.jpg" class="single" /></div>
  <div><img src="003.jpg" />
    <img src="004.jpg" /></div>
  <div><img src="005.jpg" />
    <img src="006.jpg" /></div>
  <div><img src="007.jpg" /></div>
  <div><img src="008.jpg" class="single" /></div>
  <div><img src="009.jpg" /></div>
  <div><img src="010.jpg" class="single" /></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: do you mean when you click on the image you want a single image to be displayed or just specific images with the class="single"? because you can load the images by default on their own.

Comment: Is this supposed to be based on the class `single` or do you actually need to look at the image widths?

Comment: based only on the class, don't need to look at the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I fully understand your question, there's a function below that should work to suit your needs.

Here' what the function does:

1. Loop through all images in your `container` and check each if they have class `single`.
2. If not `single` then check the next element too. Wrap just the first one, or both if the second one is also not a `single`.
3. Continue through loop, but skip the next iteration if the second element from above was also a `single`.

Here's the code with runnable snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  var skip = false;
  $('#container img').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!skip && $this.is(":not(.single)")) {
      var $next = $this.next('img');
      if ($next.is(".single")) {
        skip = false;
        $this.wrapAll("<div/>");
      } else {
        skip = true;
        $this.add($next).wrapAll("<div/>");
      }
    } else {
      skip = false
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="container">
    <img src="001.jpg" class="single" />
    <img src="002.jpg" class="single" />
    <img src="003.jpg" />
    <img src="004.jpg" />
    <img src="005.jpg" />
    <img src="006.jpg" />
    <img src="007.jpg" />
    <img src="008.jpg" class="single" />
    <img src="009.jpg" />
    <img src="010.jpg" class="single" />
</figure>
```

Comment: Based on OP's description, I think you're missing a calculation on width somewhere, as he said, `leaving the wider ones with only one image`. I don't think that the `.single` class makes any difference based on OP's code, as we have things like `<div><img src="007.jpg" /></div>` which is wrapped by its self and does not have the `single` class.

Comment: Actually, the only reason that i give an div only to 007.jpg is because the next is classed as single. Single are the wider ones, so, the scripts doesn't need to check the images width.

Comment: Yup, that's it, worked like a charm. It's more elegant and solves the problems with the pBuch's suggestion. It doesn't actually wraps the single images on a div, but nothing that an edit on the css doesn't solve.
Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately, I can't upvote you now. :p

Answer (score 0):

```
var divopen = false;
var string = "";
$("#container").children().each(function(index){
   if($(this).hasClass("single")){
      if(divopen) string += '</div>';
   string += '<div><img src="'+$(this).attr("src")+'" class="single" /></div>';
   divopen = false;
   }
   else{
      if(divopen){
         string += '<img src="'+$(this).attr("src")+'" /></div>';
         divopen = false;
      }
      else{
         string += '<div><img src="'+$(this).attr("src")+'" />';
         divopen = true;
      }
   }
});
$("#container").html(string);
```

see the [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzamk4aq/) if this fits for your application.

Comment: Well, now that I had tested it with other image configuration, when the script rebuilds the images on the div, the img loses his attributes, like classes and styles. And, well, that's a problem. Thx anyway.